# Combine dataframes in two different lists keyed on the element name in R

Tags: r, list, merge, concatenation

I have two lists `list1` and `list2` each of which contain dataframes or datatables which are uniquely identified by their name. I would like to combine the `list1` and `list2` keyed on the name of the dataset. I want the elements of both the lists to be present in the combined list. I have tried a lot of solutions from stackoverflow like `do.call(c, list1, list2)`, `Map(c, list1, list2)` or `mapply`, `merge`, `list.join`. The most success I got was by creating keys of the dataframe names and using `Map` with the keys but they did not retain the unmatched elements in the combined list, something like `keys <- unique(c(names(list1), names(list2))` and `combined_list <- Map(rbind, list1[keys], list2[keys])`. But none of them work for me the way i want.

Basically i want to perform an `rbind` on the identically named datasets that are contained in the two lists. The lists may be of different length and have different elements and sometimes overlapping elements.

What the `list1` and `list2` look like:

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:5, type =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
b <- data.frame(id = 6:10, type =c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j"))
c <- data.frame(id = 11:15, type =c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o"))

list1 <- list(a=a,b=b,c=c)

a <- data.frame(id = 16:20, type =c("p", "q", "r", "s", "t"))
b <- data.frame(id = 21:25, type =c("u", "v", "w", "x", "y"))
e <- data.frame(id = 26:30, type =c("z", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae"))
f <- data.frame(id = 31:35, type =c("ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "be"))

list2 <- list(a=a,b=b,e=e, f=f)
```

and the expected result should be like this:

```
a <- data.frame(id = c(1:5, 16:20), type =c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"))
b <- data.frame(id = c(6:10,21:25), type =c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y"))
c <- data.frame(id = 11:15, type =c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o"))
e <- data.frame(id = 26:30, type =c("z", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae"))
f <- data.frame(id = 31:35, type =c("ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "be"))

combined_list <- list(a=a, b=b, c=c, e=e, f=f)
```

Greatly appreciate any response in this regard.
P.S. This is my first post on SO. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `unique` `names` from `list1` and `list2` as you have already tried and then use them to `setnames`:

```
keys <- unique(c(names(list1), names(list2)))
x <- setNames(Map(rbind, list1[keys], list2[keys]), keys)
identical(x, combined_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

or using `lapply`:

```
x <- lapply(setNames(keys, keys), function(x) {rbind(list1[[x]], list2[[x]])})
identical(x, combined_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Your solution with the setNames worked like a miracle.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly an option would be to get both lists in one data.frame/tibble and then split by group into list items:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df_of_lists <- dplyr::union(list1 %>% 
                              purrr::map_df(as.data.frame, .id = 'name'),
                            list2 %>% 
                              purrr::map_df(as.data.frame, .id = 'name'))

split(df_of_lists, f = df_of_lists$name ) %>%
# in case you want to remove the new name colum
purrr::map( ~ .x %>% dplyr::select(-name))
```

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitury number of lists of data.frames, this could also be done with `split` and `rbind`:

```
ll <- do.call('c', list(list1, list2))
lapply(split(ll, names(ll)), function(x){
    do.call('rbind', args = c(x, list(make.row.names = F)))
})

# $a
#    id type
# 1   1    a
# 2   2    b
# 3   3    c
# 4   4    d
# 5   5    e
# 6  16    p
# 7  17    q
# 8  18    r
# 9  19    s
# 10 20    t
# 
# $b
#    id type
# 1   6    f
# 2   7    g
# 3   8    h
# 4   9    i
# 5  10    j
# 6  21    u
# 7  22    v
# 8  23    w
# 9  24    x
# 10 25    y
# 
# $c
#   id type
# 1 11    k
# 2 12    l
# 3 13    m
# 4 14    n
# 5 15    o
# 
# $e
#   id type
# 1 26    z
# 2 27   ab
# 3 28   ac
# 4 29   ad
# 5 30   ae
# 
# $f
#   id type
# 1 31   ba
# 2 32   bb
# 3 33   bc
# 4 34   bd
# 5 35   be
```

Comment: This solution worked similar to the setNames function as above.